# Strange errors while logging in scrapy

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

I had a working Spider earlier today, which I seem to have messed up by trying to change the spider module name and then revert that change.

It seems that now I get strange errors in my log as follows:

```
2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.20.2 started (bot: WebScraper)
2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.20.2 started (bot: WebScraper)
2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.20.2 started (bot: WebScraper)
2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.20.2 started (bot: WebScraper)
2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.20.2 started (bot: WebScraper)
2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.20.2 started (bot: WebScraper)
2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-01-21 17:28:59+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.20.2 started (bot: WebScraper)
```

This happens around 98 time repeating and appending those error messages, and then moves onto the next part.

```
2014-01-21 17:29:01+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2014-01-21 17:29:01+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'WebScraper.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['WebScraper.spiders'], 'LOG_FILE': 'log.txt', 'BOT_NAME': 'WebScraper'}
2014-01-21 17:29:01+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-01-21 17:29:02+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-01-21 17:29:02+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-01-21 17:29:02+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2014-01-21 17:29:02+0100 [OfferingService] INFO: Spider opened
```

Any idea why this is happening, or shall i scrap this project and start again?

Comment: Did you mess up with the `log` module somehow?

Comment: @Rho, Not that I know of, in my Spider i declare `log.start()`, and i specify any log message as `log.msg("message text", level=log.INFO)`

Comment: You don't need execute log.start() anywhere, that's done automatically by the framework and if you do so it causes weird behavior.